# unable to get request body in postman

Tags: node.js, express, post, postman

I have a controller function and an endpoint:

**controller**

```
uploadSalesOrderFromExcel : async function (req,res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        if (!req.body.branchId) {
            return res.status(400).send({ Error: "Branch Id is required." });
          }
          if (!req.file) {
            return res.status(400).send({ Error: "Excel file is required." });
          }
          const excelData = await readExcel(file, { sheet: 'Sales Order' })
          res.send(excelData);
        }
```

**route**
`http://localhost:8080/sp/salesOrders/uploadSalesOrder`

Now after hitting the API from postman, I get this response:

```
{
    "Error": "Branch Id is required."
}
```

**cURL**

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/sp/salesOrders/uploadSalesOrder \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Mzo5MTQ4MDk0ZjIxMDJhM2Q3M2U0OWY5NDljMGQ2YTIzYw==' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 164' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6bd29ccf-ebad-4299-8687-9ea46cf35686,4ea8d417-df27-49a1-8d84-3aabddbccd2c' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F branchId=5
```

Comment: Do you have a body parser setup? Express doesn't parse the body of requests by default, see [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/README.md#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

Comment: Can you post what you are getting in `req.body`

Comment: {} @Shubh only.

Comment: Then i guess you are missing` body parser` to parse the coming data .Please post your `app.js` or `index.js`

Comment: But previously made APIs are working fine. We have `body-parser`. @Shubh, When I am passing it from `raw` as `content-type:application/json`, It is working fine.

Comment: @CodeStud show the server side setup as well please

Comment: ```const config = require('./config/config');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const atob = require('atob')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');``` @James

Comment: @CodeStud update your question with the code, it will not all fit in a comment as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not used `multer`. This is why I was getting blank object in request body.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `-d` flag instead and pass the branchId as an object. try

```
  curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/sp/salesOrders/uploadSalesOrder \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Mzo5MTQ4MDk0ZjIxMDJhM2Q3M2U0OWY5NDljMGQ2YTIzYw==' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 164' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6bd29ccf-ebad-4299-8687-9ea46cf35686,4ea8d417-df27-49a1-8d84-3aabddbccd2c' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -d '{"branchId": 5}'
```

Comment: This wouldn't work anyway as the content type doesn't match the body format (JSON)